# i am trying to plot an scatter graph but the result shows only x labels . why ylabel is not display?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

in my code, if I call pred and test object I get these results.

```
Pred = array([16.88414476, 33.73226078, 75.357018  , 26.79480124, 60.49103328])
test = array([20, 27, 69, 30, 62], dtype=int64)
```

I apply:

```
plt.scatter(pred,test)
```

[image]

How I plot both pred and test results on the graph?
so please help! , how to find the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Scatter plot would take the given two values as x and y values of the plot.

If you want to plot both of them as separate data, use `plt.plot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Pred = np.array([16.88414476, 33.73226078, 75.357018  , 26.79480124, 60.49103328])
test = np.array([20, 27, 69, 30, 62])
plt.plot(Pred)
plt.plot(test, linestyle='--')
```

[image]

Use could also use the pandas plot functionality

```
pd.DataFrame({'pred': Pred, 'test': test}).plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used plt.plot but I faced an error

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to plot 2 arrays in scatter but you can do it in a plot

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Pred = np.array([16.88414476, 33.73226078, 75.357018  , 26.79480124, 60.49103328])
test = np.array([20, 27, 69, 30, 62])

plt.plot(Pred, label='Pred Label')
plt.plot(test, label='Test Label')
plt.legend() # To Show the the labels' names
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the dtype=int64 in test array has an error.

Comment: I think there is no need to use ```dtype=int64``` it will be automatically set the array type to int
If you need to make sure that each element is int you can use the following:
```array = [] # New Array
for i in test:
     array.append(int(i))
test = np.array(array)```